# Installing the subversion edge with existing Apache

Tags: apache, svn, subversion-edge

Currently I have a server running apache on it. I am trying install the subversion edge, which is shipped with apache stack to serve subversion on apache.

How to use system apache rather than using apache shipped with subversion edge?

Answer (score 2):

Deploying SubversionEdge on an existing apache is apparently [not supported](http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=402046). You could install it next to your existing Apache and use your existing installation as a reverse proxy in front of the SubversionEdge installation.

Comment: I have read the collabnet forum. 

I need to configure squid in reverse proxy mode, Right?
How I can do? 
Is there any guide to do that?